# Does abigen generated code work on Quorum?

Tags: go-ethereum

We use a fork of Quorum, and I'm trying to use Go code generated by abigen to call our contracts.  I can dial and get the client, but every call so far has died with:

"abi: attempting to unmarshall an empty string while arguments are expected"

This comes from abi.go when it tries to Unpack the results in argument.go when contract.Call is called.

I read one speculation that this message is caused by incompatible genesis blocks?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

abigen generated code works just fine on Go Quorum - nothing to do with genesis blocks. If your server IP that you are dailing and the contract IDs are not in sync, you'll get an empty result (with no error message).